# MongoDB (Java) : How to cancel map-reduce (or aggregate)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm very new to the MongoDB world and I'm connecting to a MongoDB server (2.6) using the Java driver (2.12).

Is there anyway to cancel a MapReduceCommand (or an ongoing .aggregate() operation) ? I do not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are direct API methods either, but like most mongo operations these really just function by making similar wire protocol operations to "system collections" as it were.

So the methods for finding and cancelling are documented under [**`db.currentOp()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) and [**`db.killOp()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/). Those these are the shell implementation methods all they are doing id accessing the "system collections" underneath, being `$cmd.sys.inprog` and `$cmd.sys.killop` respectively.

Specifically their shell implementations are:

**currentOp**:

```js
function ( arg ){
    var q = {}
    if ( arg ) {
        if ( typeof( arg ) == "object" )
        Object.extend( q , arg );
        else if ( arg )
        q["$all"] = true;
    }
    return this.$cmd.sys.inprog.findOne( q );
}
```

**killOp**:

```js
function (op) {
    if( !op )
        throw "no opNum to kill specified";
    return this.$cmd.sys.killop.findOne({'op':op});
}
```

This makes a simple translation in to Java code, so for instance, after determining the current operation number for the operation you wish to halt, you just issue a query as follows ( forgiving my quick cut and paste from existing Sprint data code, so whatever actual method to get the collection object ):

```java
DBCollection collection = mongoOperation.getCollection("$cmd.sys.killop");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("op", opNumber);
DBObject result = collection.findOne(query);
```

That's the basics of it. See the documentation resources listed for more information on how to match which operation you want to cancel.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer (which is correct), here is a way how you can disallow your mapreduce (or actually any other command) to run more than specific amount of time.

I found this to be really handy, because it allows you to be proactive. Note that this is only available only after **2.6**. For example here I am telling to kill my find query after 0.2 secs.

```
db.collection.find({
  // my query
}).maxTimeMS(200)
```

Look at [maxTimeMS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/) for more info.

Comment: Sure, but not only is this a new implementation for MongoDB 2.6 but it is also a cursor modifier, and though this could be applied to `aggregate` which would return a cursor in this version it does not apply to mapReduce. Or strictly does this answer the question. It's a valuable comment but not really an answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn I think in the question it was written map-reduce or aggregate. It is also written for version 2.6, so I think it is qualified as an answer. Not to point out that there are a lot of answers which tells about killOp and almost none about this new functionality.